# SQL Server Table Merger from different dedicated Servers heaving same table & database ?

Tags: sql-server

I have an Application which requires the MS Server for data storage so in application it has Id column which is Primary key , now if i run the Application with the Dedicated SQL Server in independent Systems , there are entries with their own unique Id which is auto generated in different different servers , Now my problem here is database is same here in each server also the tables , so how can i merge the data into one single server because each table has it's own Unique id value ? please help me out how can i merge the data into single table .

Comment: There are many ways but it depends on your requirements. Are all dedicated servers merging into one central database? Is anything else merging into this database? Does the central database need to merge out to the dedicated databases?

Comment: no actually the data is scattered into different regions which are not heaving the sufficient bandwidth for internet so i choose rather than creating the central server give them the dedicated sever so that after the data is completely stored in database i can take that data  and merge into the Master database .

Comment: There are many solutions. One solution is to change the master database so that the primary key is now a combination of the source systems unique id + an identifier for where that data came from. Your question is too general to answer in any more detail than that.

Answer (score 0):

Create unique schema for each client and keep the same table name in a database

Comment: But then how can i merge those table into 1 master table .

Comment: if you really want to merge into one table
Then add some site identifier value for each site master data when you are migrating the data
For example you want to merge sites X, 1 and 2 Employee master data
site x - Keep the data
site 1 - Add 100000 to all the EMPIds
Site 2 - Add 200000 to all the EMPIds
Add 100000 to EmpIds on all the referenced tables from Site1, etc
You can easily done this Using SSIS or custom SQL code